# How code an integration formula using Python

Tags: python, integration

I have an integration equations to calculate key rate and need to convert it into Python.

**The equation to calculate key rate is given by:**

[image]

**where R(n) is:**

[image]

**and p(n)dn is:**

[image]

**The key rate should be plotted like this:**

[image]

I have sucessfully plotted the static model of the graph using following equation:

```
import numpy as np
import math
from math import pi,e,log
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n1=np.arange(10, 55, 1)
n=10**(-n1/10)

Y0=1*(10**-5)
nd=0.25
ed=0.03
nsys=nd*n
QBER=((1/2*Y0)+(ed*nsys))/(Y0+nsys)
H2=-QBER*np.log2(QBER)-(1-QBER)*np.log2(1-QBER)
Rsp=np.log10((Y0+nsys)*(1-(2*H2)))
print (Rsp)

plt.plot(n1,Rsp)
plt.xlabel('Loss (dB)')
plt.ylabel('log10(Rate)')
plt.show()
```

However, I failed to plot the R^ratewise model. This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def h2(x):
    return -x*np.log2(x)-(1-x)*np.log2(1-x)

e0=0.5
ed=0.03
Y0=1e-5
nd=0.25

nt=np.linspace(0.1,0.00001,1000)
y=np.zeros(np.size(nt))
Rate=np.zeros(np.size(nt))
eta_0=0.0015


for (i,eta) in enumerate(nt):
    nsys=eta*nd
    sigma=0.9
    y[i]=1/(eta*sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))*np.exp(-(np.log(eta/eta_0)+(1/2*sigma*sigma))**2/(2*sigma*sigma))
    Rate[i]=(max(0.0,(Y0+nsys)*(1-2*h2(min(0.5,(e0*Y0+ed*nsys)/(Y0+nsys))))))*y[i]


plt.plot(nt,np.log10(Rate))
plt.xlabel('eta')
plt.ylabel('Rate')
plt.show()
```

Hopefully that anyone can help me to code the key rate with integration p(n)dn as stated above. This is the paper for referrence:
[key rate](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.08949.pdf)

Thank you.

Comment: Just want to clarify: it looks like the p(n) from the equation is the `y` in your second block of code, and the R(n) is the `Rsp` from your first block. Is that correct?

Comment: @CrepeGoat. Yes, it is.

Comment: another suggestion: instead of log-ifying your data yourself, you can use yscale to make the y-axis log-scaled. see examples in [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pyplots/pyplot_scales.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-pyplot-scales-py). (converting the x axis to decibals may still be preferred, but I can’t say for sure. if not, there’s an equivalent xscale method that works the same way.)

Answer (score 0):

<s>I copied & ran your second code block as-is, and it generated a plot. Is that what you wanted?</s>

Using `y` as the p(n) in the equation, and the `Rsp` as the R(n), you should be able to use
[NumPy's `trapz` function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html)
to approximate the integral from the sampled p(n) and R(n):

```
n = np.linspace(0, 1, no_of_samples)
# ...generate y & Rst from n...
R_rate = np.trapz(y * Rst, n)
```

However, you'll have to change your code to sample `y` & `Rst` **using the same `n`, spanning from 0 to 1`**.

---

*P.S. there's no need for the loop in your second code block; it can be condensed by removing the `i`'s, swapping `eta` for `nt`, and using NumPy's [`minimum` and `maximum` functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html), like so:*

```
nsys=nt*nd
sigma=0.9
y=1/(nt*sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))*np.exp(-(np.log(nt/eta_0)+(1/2*sigma*sigma))**2/(2*sigma*sigma))
Rate=(np.maximum(0.0,(Y0+nsys)*(1-2*h2(np.minimum(0.5,(e0*Y0+ed*nsys)/(Y0+nsys))))))*y
```

Comment: No @CrepeGoat . It sould be plotted as R^ratewise according to the figure that I have provide in the question.

Comment: @CrepeGoat.Can you share the full code after the amendmend?
I try to implement your code but I got an error.

Comment: I got only one value if I remove the i's.

Comment: regarding my suggestion at the bottom: I copied your second block of code and ran it on my machine, and it produced a plot. I then replaced the loop therein with my second block of code above, and it produced the same plot (even without the i’s). It works because NumPy is written to prform [elementwise operations between arrays](www.scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/operations.html).

Comment: regarding my main answer: I don’t have a full piece of code, because I didn’t write a full solution. I want to help you, and I wrote my answer because I think it should point you in the right direction enough that you can work it out on your own. But I don’t want to do your job for you, because: that’s a lot of work for no reward, it would send the message that SO is a place where people will write you code for free, and it’d rob you of the chance to learn anything. I hope you understand.